# If-branch for x == "N" or "No" always runs

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, or-operator

When I run this in my program, the question goes through, however no matter the answer, the "No" option always runs. If I switch the option order, the "Y" option will only run and it will always go straight to start. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I just don't know what.

```
infoconf = raw_input("Is this information correct? Y/N: ")
    
    if infoconf == "N" or "No":
        print "Please try again."
    elif infoconf == "Y" or "Yes":
        start()
    else:
        print "That is not a yes or no answer, please try again."
```

Comment: `x == a or b` is equivalent to `(x == a) or b`. Use `x == a or x == b` to get the desired results. There are too many duplicates ..

Comment: Or the shorter version: `if infoconf in ("N", "No"):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed to be

```
infoconf = raw_input("Is this information correct? Y/N: ")

#you wrote:  infoconf == "N" or "No" but should be:
if infoconf == "N" or infoconf == "No": 
  print "Please try again."
#you wrote: infoconf == "Y" or "Yes" but should be
elif infoconf == "Y" or infoconf == "Yes": 
  start()
else:
  print "That is not a yes or no answer, please try again."
```

Short explanation:

```
when value of x = 'N'
x == 'N' or 'No' will return True
when value of x = 'Y'
x == 'N' or 'No' will return 'No' i believe this is not what you want
```

at the other side

```
when value of x = 'N'
x == 'N' or x == 'No' will return True
when value of x = 'Y'
x == 'N' or x == 'No' will return False i believe this is what you want
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Hopefully that will not make you confuse anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Python will interpret `infoconf == "N" or "No"` differently than you thought. This is somewhat a case of "operator precedence" where your condition is parsed as `(infoconf == "N") or ("No")`.

Now, `infoconf == "N"` may or may not be true, but `"No"` is "something" and when treated as a logical evaluates as true. In effect, your condition `infoconf == "N" or true` will always be true.

As many others suggested, comparing `infoconf` to `"No"` in your second logical term will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do something like this:

```
infoconf = raw_input("Is this information correct? Y/N: ")

if infoconf.lower().startswith('n'):
   # No
elif infoconf.lower().startswith('y'):
   # Yes
else:
   # Invalid
```

This means that the user could reply "Y/y/yes/yeah" for yes, and "N/n/no/nah" for no.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it's a bit easier to do this as:

```
infoconf = raw_input("Is this information correct? Y/N: ")

if infoconf in ["N", "No"]:
    print "Please try again."
elif infoconf in ["Y", "Yes"]:
    start()
else:
    print "That is not a yes or no answer, please try again."
```

As others have said, `if infoconf == "N" or "No"` is equivilent to `if (infoconf == "N") or "No"`, and since `"No"` (as a non-empty string) evaluates to True, the statement will always be true.

Also, to be a little less picky on the input, you might want to do `infoconf = infoconf.strip().lower()` before you do the tests (and then compare to the lower case versions).